# When defining a function, are you also declaring it?

Tags: c++

When defining a function in the class body, are you always declaring it or how would you say? Here is an example:

```
class ss 
{
ss() {}
};
```

Are we then declaring the constructor, defining the constructor, or declaring AND defining the constructor. What could you say about this?

Comment: "When defining a function, are you also declaring it?" : Yes.

Answer (score 5):

You're both declaring and defining the constructor.

A declaration only would look like:

```
class ss 
{
  ss();
}
```

You can seperate the definition and declaration outside the class to show the obvious difference between the two:

```
class ss 
{
  ss(); //declaration
}

ss::ss() {} // definition
```

A definition is by definition a declaration too.

A declaration is only the signature of a function, a definition includes the actual function body.

Comment: Thanks! "A definition is by definition a declaration too.", please look at the comment to Angew's answer.. I would have asked you the same. Like in your second example, are you declaring the constructor twice then?

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to functions, but is a general rule in C++: **A definition is one possible type of declaration.** (This follows from the C++ grammar). Which means every definition is also a declaration.

So in your case, the constructor is both declared and defined by the declaration `ss() {}`.

Comment: Thanks. You say "Which means every definition is also a declaration.". So when only declaring the function in the class and defining it outside the class body, am I declaring the function twice? :/

Comment: @JakeBlandon Yes. And it's perfectly normal.

Comment: Hmm okay then.. But I really thought that objects and functions only could be declared once, so that is not true?

Comment: @JakeBlandon Of course not. They can only be *defined* once. But this is perfectly valid code: `class X; class X; class X {};`. A *lot* of header files with class forward declarations would break horribly if you could only declare once.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is both definition and declaration.

**The below information is lifted from C++ standards document: (n4659)**

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf

for example consider the below function

```
 int max(int a, int b, int c)
 { 
    int m = (a > b) ? a : b; 
    return (m > c) ? m : c; 
 }
```

1. int (return type of the function) is the declaration specifier
2. max(int a, int b, int c) is the declarator;
3. { /* ... */ } is the function-body.